# Ubuntu 14.04 login loop Unity terminated with status 1

Tags: 14.04, unity, login, lightdm, login-screen

I have ubuntu 14.04 and am stuck in a login loop problem despite trying the common answers to the multitude of questions on the site ,none have worked. I can't figure out what's wrong and would be happy to try and provide log information, given some guidance in how to do that.

- I can get to recovery mode
- I can get to tty root shell prompts

Results of `cat ~/.xsession-errors`

> Script for ibus started at run_im
>
> Script for auto started at run_im
>
> Script for default started at run_im.
>
> init: gnome-session (Unity) main process (1480) terminated with status 1
>
> init: unity-settings-daemon main process (1467) killed by TERM signal
>
> init: logrotate main process (1384) killed be TERM signal
>
> init: update-notifier-crash (/var/crash/lightdm.0.crash) main process (1420) 
>   killed by TERM signal
>
> init: update-notifier-crash (/var/crash/_user_bin_Xorg.0.crash) killed by TERM signal
>
> init update-notifier-crash (/var/crash/_usr_lib_ibus_ibus-ui-gtk3.1000.crash) main process 1426 killed by TERM signal
>
> init: upstart-dbus-session-bridge main process (1446) terminated with status 1
>
> init: xsession-init main proess (1464) killed by TERM signal
>
> init: hud main process (1472) killed by TERM signal
>
> init: unity-panel-service main process (1484) killed by TERM signal
>
> init: Disconnected from notified D-bus bus

Results of '    lsmod|grep fglrx'

> fglrx               13510274 0
>
> amd_iommu_v2           19054 1 fglrx

Things I've tried from answers to reading various questions on askubuntu about login loops include the following

- Changing permissions of contents of my home directory, (specifically xauthority as well)
- Installing, reinstalling, restarting lightdm, gdm, lxde (desktop environment)
- Creating a new user and logging in from there (doesn't work for guest or the new test user I've created)
- Booting into recovery mode and using the dpkg function
- sudo chmod 777 ~/.ICEauthority (now it's owned by user rather than root?)
- resetting unity with the unity tweak tool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nobody properly explained the fact that there's a button on the login screen I can press to change desktop environments to access the lubuntu desktop environment I previously installed.

xfce/xubuntu and lxde/lubuntu work, cinnamon unfortunately does not. Unity being the awful mess it is doesn't and is why I went through this all.